# If normal to curve $x=3\cos\theta-\cos^3{\theta}$ and $y=3\sin\theta-\sin^3{\theta}$ at point $P(\theta)$ passes through the origin, then $\theta=$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

> If normal to curve $x=3\cos\theta-\cos^3{\theta}$ and $y=3\sin\theta-\sin^3{\theta}$ at point $P(\theta)$ passes through the origin, then $\theta=$
>
> (A) $0$
>
> (B) $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
>
> (C) $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
>
> (D) $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$

**My Approach:**

I got the slope of normal as $\tan^3{\theta}.$

So equation of normal will be $$y-3\sin\theta +\sin^3{\theta}=\tan^3{\theta \cdot(x-3\cos\theta+3\cos^3{\theta})}$$

Because it passes through origin so I put $x=0,y=0$, which lead me to the equation,

$$3\sin\theta \cdot \cos{\theta} \cdot\cos{2\theta}=0$$

So value of $\theta$ will be $\theta=0, \dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{4}.$

But answer given is only $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

**My doubt:**

Why option (A) and (C) are wrong.

Comment: Here is the graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iftoU.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation should be:
$$(y-3\sin{\theta}+\sin^3{\theta}) = \tan^3{\theta}(x-3\cos{\theta}+\cos^3{\theta})$$
When you rewrite $\tan^3{\theta}$ as $\frac{\sin^3{\theta}}{\cos^3{\theta}}$ and substitute $x=y=0$, you get $\tan^2{\theta}=1$ or $\sin{2\theta}=0$. Your explanation is right, $\theta=0,\frac{\pi}{2}$ work as well.

Comment: there are other possibilities too that is $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{2} , 0$ we can verify by putting mentioned value.

Comment: I have made the required edit. When I solved the question the first time, I canceled $\frac{1}{2}\sin{2\theta}$ on both sides. This may have been the mistake that the person who made the question might have made as well.